# IHttpContextAccessor scope

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have IHttpContextAccessor injected in a controller. I am reading user name from IHttpContextAccessor and returning it back to the UI.

My question is is very basic. I need to understand how this will work when multiple users will connect and request User Name.

I just want to make sure that the user names will be returned only for the corresponding user.

I don't want to save the user name in session variable after returned to the client. Whenever is needed, I will request a call and get it from the context.

Is this approach valid?

```
private IHttpContextAccessor ctx
public EmployeeController(IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
  ctx=context;
}

public string GetEmployeeName()
{
   return ctx.HttpContext.User.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Yes this approach is valid. It will return the username of corresponding user.

Comment: Thank you Abhay, what if the GetEmployee name is called again for some other user? Will it return the for the corresponding user? Just want to understand the scope of httpcontext when multiple users are logged in?

Comment: You need not to worry. It always gives you the current request context, so it will be different for other user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpContextAccessor  will be registered as the Singleton service when you
called  AddHttpContextAccessor.

According to the [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs), you could find the HttpContextAccessor will check the _httpContextCurrent value when it call get and set method. It will auto set the _httpContextCurrent.Value when the new request come to the application.